# How to enable Oracle JDK 8 patch upgrades on an existing JDK 8 installation in CentOS

Tags: centos, jdk

How to enable Oracle JDK 8 patch upgrades on an existing JDK 8 installation in CentOS. Refer details in the original thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089608/how-to-remote-download-the-latest-jdk8

Comment: i don't think you can easily get a server application running in a jvm, to run in a new jvm, with no downtime.

Comment: Just need to know the process of migration?

Comment: Any pointers would be welcome

Comment: oracle jvm rpms maintain a symlink /usr/java/latest to the latest version installed; you could that for your java_home, but installing an updated version will obviously not change the running jvm. you could have two instances (proxied thru haproxy or apache load-balancer), and restart one at a time

Answer (score 0):

You want to update jdk8 using "yum update"?

Either with `yum localinstall $NEWRPM` (manual solution)

OR build a repository containing the oracle-rpms and reference that enabled repositoy in **/etc/yum.repos.d/**

After this `yum update` should also update oracle-jdk.